# How to maintain the index of each member in a separate directory?

Tags: solr

I am using solr 3.6.2 to index e-mail. Now the index is stored in the directory / solr / data / index. How to configure users save index in separate directories? For example: user ppp index files stored in the directory / solr / data / index / ppp.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Solr index directory structure should be treated as internal, and not manipulated.

Comment: We develop webmail. Buyer does not want to index files it maildata were in the same directory where the index files of other users.

Comment: Use a different core for each user then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If separation is your concern, use separate core both at index and query time, one of the uses of Solr's multicore support is to support multitenant applications. That way you never mix each client's data.

In Solr  4.1 and 4.5 on, has co-locate concept. Read more about here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud

Comment: I still can not understand how to configure this. I work with solr recently. =(